# Is it possible to iterate through attributes of a namespace object?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I couldn't find any answers on this one, but I think I'm not the first one to ask this question. So if it's double - please forgive me :)

This code:

```
from multiprocessing import Manager

manager = Manager()
global_vars = manager.Namespace()

global_vars.x = 0
global_vars.y = True
global_vars.z = "hello"
print(global_vars)
```

prints:

```
 Namespace(x=0, y=True, z='hello')
```

If I use this namespace object in a different process (using multiprocessing), it is possible to iterate through the namespace object without knowing which variables are in there? So something like:

```
for var in global_vars:
  print(var)
```

Comment: Maybe `for var in vars(global_vars)` ?

Comment: @DeepSpace: That doesn't work, none of the the values of `var` are the attributes of `global_vars` needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another, slightly less hacky answer than my earlier (and now deleted) one.

As it turns out, `global_vars` is actually a `NamespaceProxy`, not a `Namespace`, instance, due to how `multiprocessing.Manager`s work. The former class has a `__dict__`, which is where its attributes are stored.

It's still hacky because it uses the *private* `_getvalue()` method that `NamespaceProxy` inherits from its `BaseProxy` base class to get a *copy* of the value of the underlying `Namespace` object's `__dict__`. Besides the potential issue that may cause (i.e. not being up-to-date), the usual risks of using any private method apply, such as the fact that they might change or even disappear at some point in the future without notice, and the fact that using them breaks [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)).

That said, borrowing the title of a book on C++ by Allen Holub, here's enough rope to shoot yourself in the foot: `;¬)`

```
from multiprocessing import Manager


if __name__ == '__main__':

    manager = Manager()
    global_vars = manager.Namespace()
    global_vars.x = 0
    global_vars.y = True
    global_vars.z = "hello"

    for var in global_vars._getvalue().__dict__:
        print(var)
```

Output:

```
x
y
z
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! It seems to work, but as you say it is a bit hacky. But I'm affraid there's no better way to do it, so for now I'll use this approach.

Comment: It just a workaround for the fact that `multiprocessing.Manager.Namespace` object don't provide a way to do what's needed (so the only recourse is to become dependent on its current implementation). Perhaps you should use a `multiprocessing.Manager.dict` instead. Regardless, please consider accepting my answer since, as you say, it works and more importantly, answers the question you asked.

Comment: sorry forgot to accept your answer. Thanks again, I'll also give the multiprocessing.Manager.dict is try, that could be a better alternative indeed.

Comment: FWIW, if using dictionaries is too awkward, I think it would fairly easy to create a custom `Namespace`-like class that was iterable and make it work with a `multiprocessing,Manager`.